# Most efficient paradigm for checking if a key exists in a c++ std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, performance, std, unordered-map

I am relatively new to modern c++ and working with a foreign code base.  There is a function that takes a std::unordered_map and checks to see if a key is present in the map. The code is roughly as follows

```
uint32_t getId(std::unordered_map<uint32_t, uint32_t> &myMap, uint32_t id) 
{
   if(myMap.contains(id))
   {
     return myMap.at(id);
   }
   else
   {
     std::cerr << "\n\n\nOut of Range error for map: "<< id << "\t not found" << std::flush;
     exit(74);
   }
}
```

It seems like calling `contains()` followed by `at()` is inefficient since it requires a double lookup.  So, my question is, what is the most efficient way to accomplish this?  I also have a followup question: assuming the map is fairly large (~60k elements) and this method gets called frequently how problematic is the above approach?

After some searching, it seems like the following paradigms are more efficient than the above, but I am not sure which would be best.

- Calling `myMap.at()` inside of a `try-catch` construct

  - Pros: `at` automatically throws an error if the key does not exist
  - Cons: `try-catch` is apparently fairly costly and also constrains what the optimizer can do with the code
- Use `find`

  - Pros: One call, no `try-catch` overhead
  - Cons: Involves using an iterator; more overhead than just returning the value

```
    auto findit = myMap.find(id);
    if(findit == myMap.end())
    {
      //error message;
      exit(74); 
    }
    else
    {
      return findit->first;
    }
```

Comment: What makes you think an iterator is more overhead?

Comment: "more overhead than just returning the value". Show your measurements.

Comment: @hyde I'm not sure it's actually more overhead, I just saw that argument while I was searching and is part of why I'm asking this question. The claim I saw was you need to a) construct and return the iterator object and b) you need a dereference operation to get the value from the iterator hence "more overhead"

Comment: The iterator holds a pointer to the element. So the "overhead" is constructing a pointer, and dereference a pointer. Compare that to traversing a tree structure...

Comment: These things should be optimized by compilers and in the end this should not introduce any additional overhead (for using iterators). This assume you enabled compiler optimizations but it make only sense to compare the time of optimized programs. Two lookup cannot be optimized by compilers in most cases. Still the cost of the second fetch is often significantly faster because the result will already be in the L1 cache. In fact, the use of iterator for std::vector does not introduce any overhead with mainstream compilers like gcc/clang/icc for example (on optimized programs).

Comment: I do not quite understand why a `try-catch` block would be costly.

Comment: A try-catch block is not expensive unless exceptions are raised. This assumes that the target compiler performs a "zero-cost" implementation of exception which is AFAIK the cast for all mainstream C++ compilers. The thing is if the OP is in a case where the key is often not found, then the cost can be really huge compare to the iterator case. Fortunately, the `contains` condition prevent this happening so exceptions are very cheap here. It still introduce an additional check which is negligible because it can be fully predicted by modern processors. The cost actually comes from the `contains`.

Comment: The OP calls `exit(74)` in case of an error. If should not matter if the program takes a few microseconds longer to exit because the exception is handled.

Comment: Besides the cost introduced by the possible code cache misses due to exceptions resulting in a bigger code, which tends to be often negligible in usual cases, indeed, exceptions should be Ok here. I wrongly assumed the `exit` part was just for testing purposes but I am unsure about this.

Answer (score 8):

You can do

```
// stuff before
{
    auto findit = myMap.find(id);
    if ( findit != myMap.end() ) {
        return findit->first;
    } else {
       exit(74);
    }
}
// stuff after
```

or with the new C++17 init statement syntax

```
// stuff before
if ( auto findit = myMap.find(id); findit != myMap.end() ) {
    return findit->first;
} else {
   exit(74);
}
// stuff after
```

Both define the iterator reference only in local scope. As the interator use is most definitively optimized away, I would go with it. Doing a second hash calculation will be slower almost for sure.

Also note that `findit->first` returns the *key* not the *value*. I was not sure what you expect the code to do, but one of the code snippets in the question returns the value, while the other one returns the key

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't get enough speedup within only removing the extra lookup operation and if there are millions of calls to getId in a multi-threaded program, then you can use an N-way map to be able to parallelize the id-checks:

```
template<int N>
class NwayMap
{
    public:
    NwayMap(uint32_t hintMaxSize = 60000)
    { 
         // hint about max size to optimize initial allocations
         for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
             shard[i].reserve(hintMaxSize/N);
    }
    
    void addIdValuePairThreadSafe(const uint32_t id, const uint32_t val)
    {
        // select shard
        const uint32_t selected = id%N; // can do id&(N-1) for power-of-2 N value

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut[selected]);

        auto it = shard[selected].find(id);
        if(it==shard[selected].end())
        {
            shard[selected].emplace(id,val);
        }
        else
        {
            // already added, update?
        }
    }

    uint32_t getIdMultiThreadSafe(const uint32_t id)
    {
        // select shard
        const uint32_t selected = id%N; // can do id&(N-1) for power-of-2 N value

        // lock only the selected shard, others can work in parallel
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(mut[selected]);

        auto it = shard[selected].find(id);
        // we expect it to be found, so get it quicker
        // without going "else"
        if(it!=shard[selected].end())
        {
              return it->second;
        }
        else
        {
              exit(74);
        }
    }

    private:
    std::unordered_map<uint32_t, uint32_t> shard[N];
    std::mutex mut[N];
};
```

Pros:

- if you serve each shard's getId from their own CPU threads, then you benefit from N*L1 cache size.
- even within single thread use case, you can still interleave multiple id-check operations and benefit from instruction-level-parallelism because checking id 0 would have different independent code path than checking id 1 and CPU could do out-of-order execution on them (if pipeline is long enough)

Cons:

- if a lot of checks from different threads collide, their operations are serialized and the locking mechanism causes extra latency
- when id values are mostly strided, the parallelization is not efficient due to unbalanced emplacement

Comment: OP doesn't mention threads, so I'm not sure how this is actually useful to them. You might want to add explanation on when and why something like this is worth the trouble...

Comment: I edited answer with extra info on pros/cons for the usefulness scenarios and got rid of that long typename.

Answer (score 0):

> - Calling `myMap.at()` inside of a `try-catch` construct
>
>   - Pros: `at` automatically throws an error if the key does not exist
>   - Cons: `try-catch` is apparently fairly costly and also constrains what the optimizer can do with the code

Your implementation of `getId` terminates application, so who cares about exception overheads?

Please note that most compilers (AFAIK all) implement C++ exceptions to have zero cost when exception is not thrown. Problem appears when stack is unwinded when exception is thrown and matching exception handler. I read somewhere that penalty when exception is thrown is x40 comparing to case when stack is unwinded by simple returns (with possible error codes).

Since you want to just terminate application then this overhead is negligible.